# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicalsi in matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

why I can't run this function? And the error message like the title show?

```
function y = contrast_stretching(citra)
double_citra = double (citra);
[m n] = size (citra);
for i = 1:m
    for i =1:n
        y(i,j) = double_citra(i,j) + 100;
    end;
end;
y=uint8 (y);
imshow(y);
```

Comment: Please post the question details in the question, and a statement of the question (such as "Unexpected Error in Matlab") in the question!

Answer (score 3):

Well for a start, your second for-loop is

```
for i=1:n
```

Where I suspect you actually mean:

```
for j=1:n
```

Both `i` and `j` have the default value of `sqrt(-1)` in Matlab. When you try to assign to `y(i,j)`, you're assigning to the `sqrt(-1)`th column of `y`.

Comment: Thanks for edit @slayton - That completely slipped my mind. As you say, it's generally recommended you don't use `i` and `j` as indices, as they are also symbolic variables for the imaginary unit. I tend to use `ii`,`jj`, `kk`, etc instead.